# Which one is called first, before_create or model validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i had defined a method in a Model class which is called on `before_create` which would set the attributes of the model and had also declared the validations for those attributes. I wanted to know which is called first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validations are invoked first. From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

```
(-) save
(-) valid
(1) before_validation
(-) validate
(2) after_validation
(3) before_save
(4) before_create
(-) create
(5) after_create
(6) after_save
(7) after_commit
```